# How to use Redis as a cache backend for Nginx (uwsgi module)

Tags: caching, nginx, redis, uwsgi

I'm using Nginx with UWSGI and I want Nginx to perform caching.

I know that there is a `uwsgi_cache` which can be used to cache pages on the local file system. But i want to use Redis to cache pages on memory

How is this possible?

**UPDATE:**

I don't want to proxy requests to Redis and serve content out of it. I want Nginx to proxy requests to UWSGI and perform caching, which is possible using the `uwsgi_cache` parameter but the problem is that it only caches on file system not anything else.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556063/using-nginx-to-serve-content-directly-out-of-a-redis-cache

Comment: sorry, but i can't figure out how is this duplicate of that.

Comment: Did you look at https://github.com/desbouis/nginx-redis-proxy?

Comment: No. Thank you this would help. I suggest you put this as an answer :)