# nginx can return the cache without invoke the node code?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have nodejs application and `/foo/123` endpoint that access to database to return the data.

```
router.get('/foo/123', (req, res) => {
 const data = getData();
 res.json({ data });
});
```

I want to cache this url for 30 minutes. everyone who invoke the url will get the results from the cache.

I know I can do it with redis to store the data and return the results.
I also know I can set 304 header.

I was thinking to solve it with nginx. using nginx cache to return the data from the url.

My question is does nginx support cache in this way? I mean nginx will stop the request and return the results form the cache without invoking the node code

The user can make a request from the browser (ajax) and can do the request using `curl` command.

Comment: use caching library, ex.: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache

Comment: or use proxy_pass caching: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/node-js-best-practices-nginx-2f00b48b75e

Comment: What is your frontend? If `nginx` then it would be much simplier, like @num8er said.

Comment: no. it's server: `/api/foo/123`

Comment: @JonSud got you, then you need some 3rd-party nginx module, like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4566658/973254 or manually (with `cron` help) store static file and serve it with `nginx`, but will it be a good idea to launch nginx for single location with cached file?