# How should I go about using Redis for creating notifications with express/nodejs?

Tags: node.js, redis, server-sent-events

Okay so I have a Nodejs/Express app that has an endpoint which allows users to receive notifications by opening up a connection to said endpoint:

```
var practitionerStreams = [] // this is a list of all the streams opened by pract users to the 
backend

async function notificationEventsHandler(req, res){ 
  const headers ={
      'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
  } 

  const practEmail = req.headers.practemail
  console.log("PRACT EMAIL", practEmail)

  const data = await ApptNotificationData.findAll({
      where: {
          practEmail: practEmail
      }
  })

  //console.log("DATA", data)

  res.writeHead(200, headers)
  await res.write(`data:${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`) 

  // create a new stream
  const newPractStream = {
    practEmail: practEmail,
    res
  }

  // add the new stream to list of streams
  practitionerStreams.push(newPractStream)


  req.on('close', () => {
    console.log(`${practEmail} Connection closed`);
    practitionerStreams = practitionerStreams.filter(pract => pract.practEmail !== pract.practEmail);
  });
  
  return res

}

async function sendApptNotification(newNotification, practEmail){
    var updatedPractitionerStream = practitionerStreams.map((stream) => 
    // iterate through the array and find the stream that contains the pract email we want
    // then write the new notification to that stream
    
    { 
      if (stream["practEmail"]==practEmail){
        console.log("IF")
        stream.res.write(`data:${JSON.stringify(newNotification)}\n\n`)
        
        return stream
    }
    else {
      // if it doesnt contain the stream we want leave it unchanged
      console.log("ELSE")
      return stream
    }
    }
  )
  
  practitionerStreams = updatedPractitionerStream  
  }
```

Basically when the user connects it takes the response object (that will stay open), will put that in an Object along with a unique email, and write to it in the future in `sendApptNotification`

But obviously this is slow for a full app, how exactly do I replace this with Redis? Would I still have a `Response` object that I write to? Or would that be replaced with a redis stream that I can subscribe to on the frontend? I also assume I would store all my streams on redis as well

edit: from what examples I've seen people are writing events from redis to the response object

Thank you in advance

Comment: In the other words, you want to understand how you can use redis to build a otimized notification service, right? So, you just believe that your solution isn't scalable and isn't otimized, right?

Comment: Exactly, I'm confused as to which part of my code is supposed to be replaced. Do I keep `res` and write the Redis events to that? And continue listening to my endpoint with `EventSource`? That's what I've seen, but wouldn't it be better to forgo `res` altogether and just have the frontend write directly to redis streams that I can also listen to with `EventSource`? I'm just lost on where exactly I should be using Redis

Comment: Why are you using stream to send notifications to frontend? Do you really need a real time notifications? I think it's more simple to create an endpoint in your api and the frontend do a pooling requests to get notifications. I can propose a complete answer for you but first I need to understand more why you are using streams.

Comment: In this example that I made you can use redis too, but instead of use streams, your endpoint like /notifications can receive with params or body, your userId in your jwt for example and get from the redis the last notifications

Comment: @JulienAmbrosio Yes I'm creating an app where users can receive notifications updates when they get an appointment request. You mean long polling? That is more resource intensive so I don't use it.

Comment: Not long polling. What I meant to say was do requests with setInterval in your code, for example, do requests each 5 seconds, finding the notifications in your frontend

Comment: That's possible as well, what difference would it make? would I not still need to redis streams? Or a different redis service?

Comment: Couldn't I just do the whole thing in Redis as well, where the frontend writes and listens to a specific stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Redis Stream as notification system, you can follow this official guide:
https://redis.com/blog/how-to-create-notification-services-with-redis-websockets-and-vue-js/ .
To get this data as real time you need to create a websocket connection. I prefer to send to you an official guide instead of create it for you it's because the quality of this guide. It's perfect to anyone understand how to create it, but you need to adapt for your reality, of course.

However like I've said to you in the comments, I just believe that it's more simple to do requests in your api endpoint like /api/v1/notifications with setInterval in your frontend code and do requests each 5 seconds for example. If you prefer to use a notification system as real time I think you need to understand why do you need it, so in the future you can change your system if you think you need it. Basically it's a trade-off you must to do!

For my example imagine two tables in a relational database, one as Users and the second as Notifications.
The tables of this example:

```
UsersTable
id  name
1   andrew
2   mark

NotificationTable
id  message    userId  isRead
1   message1    1       true
2   message2    1       false
3   message3    2       false
```

The endpoint of this example will return all cached notifications that isn't read by the user. If the cache doesn't exists, it will return the data from the database, put it on the cache and return to the user. In the next call from API, you'll get the result from cache. There some points to complete in this example, for example the query on the database to get the notifications, the configuration of time expiration from cache and the another important thing is: if you want to update all the time the notifications in the cache, you need to create a middleware and trigger it in the parts of your code that needs to notify the notifications user. In this case you'll only update the database and cache. But I think you can complete these points.

```
const redis = require('redis');
const redisClient = redis.createClient();

app.get('/notifications', async (request, response) => {
    const userId = request.user.id;
    const cacheResult = await redisClient.get(`user:${userId}:notifications`)

    if (cacheResult) return response.send(cacheResult);

    const notifications = getUserNotificationsFromDatabase(userId); 

    redisClient.set(`user:${userId}:notifications`, notifications);

    response.send(notifications);
})
```

Besides that there's another way, you can simple use only the redis or only the database to manage this notification. Your relational database with the correct index will send to your the results as faster as you expect. You'll only think about how much notifications you'll have been.

Comment: @Amon Did I help you with your problem?

Comment: Hey thank you so much for this, this makes sense. Also you're saying that it would be even faster to send a request from the front-end directly to my redis service correct? Additionally, when I want to create a new notification I would just have another endpoint to write to that Reddit cache correct? Thanks again this was a big help!

Comment: Thats impossible. You need an api or websocket to interfacing your redis with your frontend. The second point. You can create a middleware or a service and trigger when you need to update the cache. So you can call it around all of your endpoints, not only a specific endpoint

Comment: @Amon can you put my answer as answered in stackoverflow if Did I helped you? It will help me a lot :)

Comment: Yes couldnt I just put the redis service (lets say its in Docker) behind nginx then send redis commands directly to it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556063/using-nginx-to-serve-content-directly-out-of-a-redis-cache https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/redis/

Comment: Those are two examples but it seems that it's faster to use redis in my API

Comment: Amon, what I mean to say is you need an interface between your frontend and the redid. Can be an api, can be Nginx, can be a websocket and etc.

Comment: okay thought so. This is where my general confusion was too when asking this question. Where exactly Redis should be placed. Nginx looks possible but the API seems most common